# What is the maximal domain of these functions?

Tags: functions

Need help figuring out, how to find the maximal domains of functions

$f(x) = \frac{x^3-x}{2x^2+1}$

$f(x) = \frac{x^2-5x+6}{x-2}$

Comment: I guess $f$ should be dependant on $y$ and $z$, not on $x$? Considering finding the domain: The domain of $f$ is the set of arguments for which $f$ is well-defined. So you need to ask yourself "when is $\frac{a}{b}$ not well-defined?".

Comment: please clarify the domain of function argument

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose $f(x)$ should be $f(y)$ and $f(z)$ and that we are working in $\mathbb{R}$.

1. This is a rational expression. The only restriction is that the denominator is not $0$. Since
   $$2y^2+1=0$$
   has no solution then the denominator does not impose any restriction on the domain. Hence $dom(f)=\mathbb{R}$.
2. Same thinking leads to
   $$z-2\ne 0 \Leftrightarrow z\ne 2.$$
   The domain is $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{2\}$.

Comment: function argument could be complex.

Answer (score 0):

The second function does not contain $z=2$ in the domain, but it can be extended continuously at this point, thus defined continuous, so the maximal domain would be all real numbers.